# Low potassium in blood

Tags: blood

A blood test revealed low potassium. What is the dangerous effect of low potassium in the blood? Is medication necessary for this condition?

Thank you for your wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

Low potassium is on average below 3.5 and is termed [hypokalemia](http://www.mayoclinic.org/symptoms/low-potassium/basics/when-to-see-doctor/sym-20050632). Signs and symptoms:

> Weakness Fatigue Muscle cramps Constipation
>
> Abnormal heart rhythms (arrhythmias) are the most worrisome
>   complication of very low potassium levels, particularly in people with
>   underlying heart disease.

Severely low potassium can result in death.

[Ncbi](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21264075)

[Medication, surgery and diet can be used to treat hypokalemia.](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/242008-treatment#d10) However. Medications are not always use s to treat unless you consider potassium supplement. Treatment depends on cause, as well.

> Medications
>
> Usually, oral potassium chloride is administered when potassium levels
>   need to be replenished, as well as, in patients with ongoing potassium
>   loss (eg, those on thiazide diuretics), when it must be maintained.
>   Potassium-sparing diuretics are generally used only in patients with
>   normal renal function who are prone to significant hypokalemia.
>
> Angiotensin-converting enzyme (ACE) inhibitors, which inhibit renal
>   potassium excretion, can ameliorate some of the hypokalemia that
>   thiazide and loop diuretics can cause. However, ACE inhibitors can
>   lead to lethal hyperkalemia in patients with renal insufficiency who
>   are taking potassium supplements or potassium-sparing diuretics.
>
> Surgical care
>
> Generally, hypokalemia is a medical, not a surgical, condition.
>   Surgical intervention is required only with certain etiologies, such
>   as the following:
>
> Renal artery stenosis Adrenal adenoma Intestinal obstruction producing
>   massive vomiting Villous adenoma Decreasing Potassium Losses Measures
>   to identify and stop ongoing losses of potassium include the
>   following:
>
> Discontinue diuretics/laxatives Use potassium-sparing diuretics if
>   diuretic therapy is required (eg, severe heart failure) Treat diarrhea
>   or vomiting Administer H2 blockers to patients receiving nasogastric
>   suction Control hyperglycemia if glycosuria is present
>
> Because of the risk associated with potassium replacement, alleviation
>   of the cause of hypokalemia may be preferable to treatment, especially
>   if hypokalemia is mild, asymptomatic, or transient and is likely to
>   resolve without treatment. For example, patients with vomiting who are
>   successfully treated with antiemetics may not require potassium
>   replacement.
>
> Replenishment of Potassium Replenishment of potassium is the second
>   treatment step. For every 1 mEq/L decrease in serum potassium, the
>   potassium deficit is approximately 200-400 mEq.
>
> Bear in mind, however, that many factors in addition to the total body
>   potassium stores contribute to the serum potassium concentration.
>   Therefore, this calculation could either overestimate or underestimate
>   the true potassium deficit. For example, do not overcorrect potassium
>   in patients with periodic hypokalemic paralysis. This condition is
>   caused by transcellular maldistribution, not by a true deficit.
>
> Patients who have mild or moderate hypokalemia (potassium level of
>   2.5-3.5 mEq/L) are usually asymptomatic; if these patients have only minor symptoms, they may need only oral potassium replacement therapy.
>   If cardiac arrhythmias or significant symptoms are present, then more
>   aggressive therapy is warranted. This treatment is similar to the
>   treatment of severe hypokalemia.
>
> If the potassium level is less than 2.5 mEq/L, intravenous potassium
>   should be given. Maintain close follow-up care, provide continuous ECG
>   monitoring, and check serial potassium levels.
>
> Higher dosages may increase the risk of cardiac complications. Many
>   institutions have policies that limit the maximum amount of potassium
>   that can be given per hour. Hospital admission or observation in the
>   emergency department is indicated; replacement therapy takes more than
>   a few hours.
>
> The serum potassium level is difficult to replenish if the serum
>   magnesium level is also low. Look to replace both.
>
> Oral potassium is absorbed readily, and relatively large doses can be
>   given safely. Oral administration is limited by patient tolerance
>   because some individuals develop nausea or even gastrointestinal
>   ulceration with enteral potassium formulations.
>
> Intravenous potassium, which is less well tolerated because it can be
>   highly irritating to veins, can be given only in relatively small
>   doses, generally 10 mEq/h. Under close cardiac supervision in emergent
>   circumstances, as much as 40 mEq/h can be administered through a
>   central line. Oral and parenteral potassium can safely be used
>   simultaneously.
>
> Take ongoing potassium losses into consideration by measuring the
>   volume and potassium concentration of body fluid losses. If the
>   patient is severely hypokalemic, avoid glucose-containing parenteral
>   fluids to prevent an insulin-induced shift of potassium into the
>   cells. If the patient is acidotic, correct the potassium first to
>   prevent an alkali-induced shift of potassium into the cells.

Answer (score -1):

Low potassium in blood is a condition called *hypokalemia*. Your doctor can possibly recommend you potassium intake.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypokalemia) article about it is fairly well documented.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Your post does not appear to answer all parts of the question. Thanks!